# Magento 1.8 product image upload on Firefox not working

Tags: php, magento, firefox

im working with Magento 1.8 and have the following problem only on Firefox ( ver.29 and ver.28, Flash Player 13 ):

When creating new products ( or editing existing ) i want to add some product images. The two buttons: Browse Files and Upload Files are visible in Firefox. After Adding some images ( size etc is correct ) the fileupload is not working ( in IE, Chrome, Safari it works...).

I used fiddler to find out whats going on:
Magento is calling ..app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\Product\GalleryController.php -> uploadAction.
On Firefox, this action is never called, instead of that, the admin panel login is screen is rendered as response.

Does anyone have the same issue? 
Maybe something is wrong with the form key?

best regards

Comment: ya i have also the same problem.I don't know what will be the soln of this problem because image is uploading in other sites in magento admin in firefox

Answer (score 2):

Installing the flash player will solve the problem, or if you have already installed then check if updates available on adobe site.

Muk Said http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Answer (score 0):

Check for the flash player

- http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

Your magento root directory should not be password protected using .htpasswd file.

Please post if you are getting any error.